# Another way for !=

Tags: c++, openmp

When I execute my code I get as output:

error : invalid controlling predicate

I know the problem is "!="

Is there any idea about how to rewrite the condition in the for loop to make it run until the last element of my array

```
typedef pair<double,double> point;
vector<point>  smallline;

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
{
    #pragma omp for 
    for (vector< vector<point> >::const_iterator it1 =   lines.begin(); it1!= lines.end(); it1++){
        smallline = (*it1);

   .
   .
   .
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of OpenMP version 5.0 you can also use the `!=` idiom for random access iterators (see OpenMP spec, page 96).

Earlier OpenMP version can only parallel simple `for`. So, your best option is:

```
typedef pair<double,double> point;

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
{
    #pragma omp for 
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++){
   .
   .
   .
   }
}
```

Comment: i just update my question. i also need to get back the (*it1)

Answer (score 2):

Since `std::vector` is defined as contiguous storage and `std::vector::end` returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the container. You can actually use `<`:

```
#pragma omp for 
for (vector<vector<point>>::const_iterator it1 = lines.begin(); it1 < lines.end(); it1++) {
```

Of course that doesn't necessarily work for other containers. But you have to adhere to the requirements of OpenMP anyway, i.e. it must be a random access iterator.

This works since OpenMP 3.0 (which is more than 10 years old).

That said, the little information about the rest of your code is concerning. You must not do `smallline = (*it1);` within the loop like that! `smalline` is *shared* by default because it is declared outside of the `paralle`l construct. Move this variable inside of the `parallel` construct to avoid this. Be careful with race conditions like that.